# Function go trought list

Tags: python

I need to create a function called catalog() to find out how many vehicles there are with the amount of wheels I choose. The only thing I can't change is the call "catalog = catalog(all_vehicles, 6)"

For example:

If I do like this

catalog = catalog(all_vehicles, 6)

It should come out like this:

"Found 2 vehicles with 6 wheels"

Or catalog = catalog(all_vehicles, 2)

"Found 4 vehicles with 2 wheels"

```
class Vehicles:
    color = ''
    wheels = []
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels):
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        
    def filter():
        pass
    
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The bus is {self.color} and has {self.wheels} wheels.")
bus1 = Vehicles("white", 6)
bus1.__str__()
bus2 = Vehicles("blue", 6)
bus2.__str__()

class Car(Vehicles):
    speed = 0
    displacement = 0
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, speed, displacement):
        super().__init__(color, wheels)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.speed = speed
        self.displacement = displacement
    
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The car is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels, is traveling at {self.speed} mph and has {self.displacement} displacement.")

car1 = Car("black", 4, 70, 1000)
car1.__str__()
car2 = Car("grey", 4, 65, 950)
car2.__str__()
car3 = Car("green", 4, 90, 1100)
car3.__str__()

class Truck(Car):
    cargo = 0
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, speed, displacement, cargo):
        super().__init__(color, wheels, speed, displacement)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.speed = speed
        self.displacement = displacement
        self.cargo = cargo
        
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The truck is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels, is traveling at {self.speed} mph, has {self.displacement} displacement and is carrying {self.cargo} weight as cargo.")
        
truck1 = Truck("grey", 4, 40, 900, 1.525)
truck1.__str__()
truck2 = Truck("white", 4, 45, 920, 2.253)
truck2.__str__()

class Bike(Vehicles):
    gears = ""
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, gears):
        super().__init__(color, wheels)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.gears = gears
        
    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The bike is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels and has {self.gears} changes.")
        
bike1 = Bike("orange", 2, 12)
bike1.__str__()
bike2 = Bike("black", 2, 10)
bike2.__str__()

class Motorbike(Bike):
    speed = 0
    displacement = 0
    model = ""
    
    def __init__(self, color, wheels, gears, speed, displacement, model):
        super().__init__(color, wheels, gears)
        self.color = color
        self.wheels = wheels
        self.gears = gears
        self.speed = speed
        self.displacement = displacement
        self.model = model

    def __str__(self):
        print(f"The motorbike is {self.color}, has {self.wheels} wheels, has {self.gears} changes, is traveling at {self.speed} mph, has {self.displacement} displacement and is a {self.model} motorbike.")

motorbike1 = Motorbike("blue", 2, 5, 120, 600, "road")
motorbike1.__str__()
motorbike2 = Motorbike("black", 2, 7, 220, 1100, "race")
motorbike2.__str__()

all_vehicles = [bus1, bus2, car1, car2, car3, truck1, truck2, bike1, bike2, motorbike1, motorbike2]

def catalog(the_list, wheels):    

    print(f"Founded {Vehicles} with {Vehicles.wheels} wheels.")

catalog = catalog(all_vehicles, 6)
```

Comment: first of all `catalog = catalog(all_vehicles, 6)` is bad, bacause after the call the function `catalog()` is no longer available. Now name `catalog` is `None` (your function does not return anything.

Comment: 1) In your classes Dunder method `__str__` should return a string (not print it,  2) you should not call the Dunder method, and 3) Use `print(bus1)` to print bus1,  The print method will then invoke the Dunder method for __str__ for the object.

Comment: Second, what's the question? It looks like you didn't do anything in the function. Perhaps this link will help you in formulating a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What's your question? How does current behavior differ from expected behavior? Please see [MRE].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you reassign `catalog` at the very end, you're overriding the definition of the function. So, subsequent invocation will fail. Also, you need some kind of loop in the `catalog` function with an accumulator. There are multiple ways to do this in Python, but I'll present the basic way that's readable to newcomers.

```py
def catalog(the_list, wheels):
  num = 0
  for vehicle in the_list:
    if vehicle.wheels == wheels:
      num += 1

  print(f"Found {num} vehicles with {wheels} wheels.")

catalog(all_vehicles, 6)
catalog(all_vehicles, 2)
```

This will help you move the ball down the field. Your data structures and naming are a bit wonky. Do you want a list for wheels? Or perhaps just store number? Your next steps are to clean up how you want to represent the data and then come back to tweak my proposed definition of `catalog`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming from how you initialize it in your objects, that `Vechicles.wheels` is an `int`

```
def catalog(the_list, wheels):   
    found = 0
    for veh in the_list:
        if veh.wheels == wheels:
            found += 1
    print(f"Found {found} with {wheels} wheels.")
```